# trying to loop trhough a column result and insert into DB2 table?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to run a query in DB2 that loops through each user id retreived from a column and inserts that into another table
with all the other values unique. I keep getting issues while trying to insert. Below is the error code .

### Can someone please help what's wrong with the below query.

```
FOR v_row AS  
SELECT Test.USR_ID FROM (SELECT usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_cust_xref ucx 
       JOIN dbo.custid_acct_xref cax 
         ON ucx.cust_id = cax.cust_id 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON cax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' 
UNION 
SELECT uax.usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_acct_xref uax 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON uax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' ) as Test


    DO           

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into cxxcow.USERS_RESOURCES(RSRC_ID,USER_ID,UR_INSERT_FG,UR_INQUIRY_FG,UR_UPDTE_FG,UR_DELETE_FG,UR_BROWSE_FG,UR_OPENCLOSE_FG,
UR_UPT_DTE,UR_UPT_USR,UR_ACCESS_DTE,UR_ACCESS_USR,UR_CODE_WORD)
values('WEB-ICD-RPBD',' || v_row.usr_id || ','N','N','Y','N','N','O',CURRENT TIMESTAMP,'AMARENDAR',CURRENT TIMESTAMP,'AMARENDAR',' ')'



END FOR
```

--Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=FOR;  GET SQL SAVEPOINT HOLD FREE ASSOCIATE, DRIVER=3.53.70
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -199

Comment: You need to escape quotes in your quoted string.

Comment: can you help me with the query please. should i use escape quotes for every field in the insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necessary in your case to use for loop, you can directly do it (better in performance and lisibility)

```
insert into cxxcow.USERS_RESOURCES
(
RSRC_ID, USER_ID, UR_INSERT_FG, UR_INQUIRY_FG, UR_UPDTE_FG, UR_DELETE_FG, UR_BROWSE_FG,
UR_OPENCLOSE_FG, UR_UPT_DTE, UR_UPT_USR, UR_ACCESS_DTE, UR_ACCESS_USR, UR_CODE_WORD
)
SELECT 'WEB-ICD-RPBD', f0.USR_ID, 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N',
'O', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'AMARENDAR', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'AMARENDAR', ' ' 
FROM 
(
SELECT usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_cust_xref ucx 
       JOIN dbo.custid_acct_xref cax 
         ON ucx.cust_id = cax.cust_id 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON cax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' 
UNION 
SELECT uax.usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_acct_xref uax 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON uax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' 
) as f0
where not exists 
(
    select * from cxxcow.USERS_RESOURCES f1
    where f0.USR_ID=f1.USER_ID

)
```

Comment: have been on this for couple of days.Thank you very much sir @Esperento57. This worked!!

Comment: just one more question on this, what if few of the records that i'm trying to insert through this are already present ? Can i make only the records that are not present inserted ?and skip the rest  without getting an error. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this approach:

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2, etc)
select 
field1, field2, etc
from other tables
```

It's logically equivalent and much simpler.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I tried this approach as well in the beginning , which never worked.

Comment: can you please check this and see if i'm missing anything

Comment: insert into cxxcow.USERS_RESOURCES('WEB-ICD-RPBD',,'N','N','Y','N','N','O',CURRENT TIMESTAMP,'AMARENDAR',CURRENT TIMESTAMP,'AMARENDAR',' ')
SELECT Test.USR_ID FROM (SELECT usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_cust_xref ucx 
       JOIN dbo.custid_acct_xref cax 
         ON ucx.cust_id = cax.cust_id 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON cax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' 
UNION 
SELECT uax.usr_id 
FROM   dbo.usr_acct_xref uax 
       JOIN dbo.acct_brdng_xref abx 
         ON uax.acct_nbr = abx.acct_nbr 
WHERE  abx.brdng_cd = 'PN' ) as Test

Comment: sory i had a Test.USR_ID in the second field in the query after 'WEB-ICD-RPBD'

Comment: The query you posted as a comment does not have the same structure as the one in my answer.  In fact, it's not even close.

Comment: can you please help me what changes i need to make if you are clear with my requirement is